# Javascript acces array element inside an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

```
var outer = new Array();
var inner = new Array();

inner[0] = "target";
outer[0] = inner;
```

So in Javascript whats the correct syntax to access the string target?

```
var target = outer[0][0];   //correct
```

or sth. like

```
var target = outer[0].[0];  //false don´t use
```

Comment: Did you try it? Which version worked? What happened? Did something go wrong?

Comment: the first one - in the second one you are trying to access a property or a method of inner, and failing miserably...

Comment: @David Thomas No i just theoriecrafted and thought it might be a good question for this exchange because some others may have similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an array you need to use

```
var target = outer[0][0];
```

The dot notation you seem to be confusing in your second suggestion is used to access object properties. So if you would have

```
var outer = new Object();
var inner = new Object();

inner.item = "target";
outer.item = inner;
```

you would use `outer.item.item` to access `"target"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
var target = outer[0][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript objects are simple associative arrays. So the following are equivalent:

```
var o = {
    a: "a"
};

alert(o.a === o["a"]); // true
```

So the following is incorrect (you can't use both the dot notation and the array index notation - just pick one):

```
var target = outer[0].[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternative (and IMHO more readable) way of writing this:

```
var outer = [ [ 'target' ] ]
,   inner = outer[0];
```

or also as

```
var inner = [ 'target' ]
,   outer = [ inner ];
```

So, `target` can be retrieved with

```
var target = outer[0][0];
```

Comment: 'outer.0.0' is not a valid syntax.

Comment: @DavidMulder: I know, I’d forgotten to remove before posting. It was gone by the time you submitted your comment (and your downvote).  :-)

Comment: Hmm, the downvote was primarily because this suggested an alternative way of writing it which was totally not relevant to the question asked (which was about retrieving items from nested arrays). The comment was separate to point out that the suggested code wouldn't work.

Comment: @DavidMulder: I see your point, but I added the alternative way of writing to illustrate what the possible Javascript notations are; which is ultimately what the OP's problem boils down to.